# Cannot successfully import csv to neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to import a CSV file to neo4j database using the following query:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///I:/Traces.csv" AS row

MERGE (e:Event {SystemCall: coalesce(row.syscall, "No Value"), ReturnValue: coalesce(row.retvalue,"No Value"), ReturnTime: coalesce(row.rettime,"No Value"), CallTime: coalesce(row.calltime,"No Value")})

MERGE (s:Subject {ProcessName: coalesce(row.processname, "No Value"), Pid: coalesce(row.pid, "No Value"), tid: coalesce(row.tid, "No Value")})
MERGE (o:Object {Argument1: coalesce(row.arg1, "No Value"), Argument2: coalesce(row.arg2, "No Value")})

MERGE (e)-[:IS_GENERATED_BY]->(s)
MERGE (e)-[:AFFECTS]->(o)
MERGE (e)-[:AFFECTS] ->(s)
```

The CSV file is hosted at location: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8vCvM9jIcTzRktRTGpxOUZXQjA

The query takes almost 80K milliseconds to run but returns no row. Please help.

Comment: When you say it "returns no row", do you mean it puts nothing in the DB? Your query has no `RETURN` clause, so it isn't supposed to "return" any rows. Also, can you just show the first few lines from the file (say the first 10)? A 40MB file is too big to expect us to download.

Comment: I was trying to mimic a similar query which worked for me to generate a graph

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/test.csv" AS line
MERGE (n:MyNode {Name:line.Source})
MERGE (m:MyNode {Name:line.Target})
MERGE (n) -[:TO {dist:line.distance}]-> (m)

This one worked fine without writing any return. Here no rows are being inserted. 

Screenshot of the file content: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8vCvM9jIcTzajgzOGdsSGd0RDQ

I did put in the underscores in the header fields and re ran the query to no good effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

1. You must not have superfluous whitespace around the comma delimiters in your CSV files. (Also, you should eliminate the extra 11 commas at the end of each line).
2. Every field name in your CSV file header has to match the corresponding property name in your Cypher query. Currently, most of the names are different.

*By the way, when talking about a Cypher query, the term "return" almost always refers to the `RETURN` clause. Your question has nothing to do with a `RETURN` clause, and is actually about data creation.*

[UPDATE]

In addition, if you want to import a huge amount of data into a brand new neo4j DB, you should consider using the [Import tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html) instead. It would be much faster than `LOAD CSV`.

Comment: Thanks cybersam. A question that I have is how do I speed up the graph generation process when I have 475K lines in the csv? Right now it takes forever...